# Would it be fine vs Would it be ok

Tags: word-choice, formality

Does *Would it be fine* sound natural or not?

Can we use this phrase in formal communication?

For example:

> I am available tomorrow at 3 pm. Would it be fine?

Comment: I believe you've found a positive-polarity item. 'It will be fine if you ...' but not 'Will it be fine if ...?' or 'It will not be fine if ...' (under normal circumstances).

Comment: I didn't get it. It's basically a question after a statement. For example, I am availabe tomorrow at 3 pm. Would it be fine?

Comment: Define "formal communications".

Comment: @HotLicks Please do refer my comment.

Comment: Communication between colleagues.

Comment: Is one of them the Queen of England?  Is the communication on a Post-It note, in a text message, or typed by your secretary on the company letterhead?

Comment: Seriously, not sure. Though, it is an email.

Comment: Who are you sending the email to? A superior, a subordinate, a client, or a colleague? How do you normally address them? How do you end the email? A simple 'best regards' or a 'your faithfully / sincerely'?

Comment: "Would that be ok?" is a more normal way to express this.

Comment: After checking quite a few examples on the internet, 'padding' seems to make 'Would that be fine' far more idiomatic. Thus 'Would that be fine for/with you?' / 'Would that be fine as long as we pay in advance?' But (and this is no doubt illogical) your bare example doesn't sound natural.

Comment: @MaxWilliams "Would that be ok?" sounds dominative. And "ok" is so informal. That's the reason I chose "fine". And used "it" to show politeness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Any comment on my logic would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow. I've just said that it is illogical that 'Would that be fine for/with you?' sounds (at least, in my opinion) a lot more natural than  'Would that be fine?' and certainly much more natural than 'Would it be fine?'

Comment: No, Raza, that could never be fine, even in informal communication. It would always be understood, and it would always reveal you to be very clearly a non-native speaker.

First, however little it matters, “I am available…” would be better as “I will be…” 

Either way, “Would it be fine?” needs two changes, even though the whole thing is purely about idiom

“Would that be OK?” does and “Would it be fine?” Doesn’t work.